# Why was my question on vlc deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

It's very clear what I'm asking, why was this questioned deleted?

https://superuser.com/questions/1038369/what-is-the-command-line-syntax-to-use-chromecast-in-vlc-3-0

> What is the command line syntax to use chromecast in VLC 3.0?

That was the title. What is the expectation for the question? Here is the contents of the now deleted question

> I just downloaded VLC 3.0 Beta (using ubuntu ppa) and I wanted to know
>   how to set it up to stream to chromecast. It's in the repo's NEWS that
>   the feature has been added. Numerous news outlets are covering it.
>   But, there is no example of how to actually use it yet.
>
> I know it's not in the GUI (having searched the source code). And, I
>   have no idea how to use the code from the command line.
>
> Here is the Ubuntu PPA that I used to install it. However, it
>   shouldn't matter. Nor, should the OS or system matter. It's just
>   software. You can build it yourself or download a binary ("nightly")
>   here.

Comment: "umerous news outlets are covering it. But, there is no example of how to actually use it yet." - So provide these references so people can do research.  The OS does matter if the different platforms are not in sync.

Comment: It's not productive to insult the people who are trying to help: "What the hell could [you] possibly want to know?", "... idiots guide ...", and "... go away."

Answer (score 2):

It was deleted because it met the criteria for the [Community roomba to delete it](https://superuser.com/help/roomba) under the "AbandonedClosed" reason:

> **question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...**
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past 9 days

No users or mods were involved in the deletion of your question.

As to why it was closed it would appear that several users believed it was unclear what you were asking. While you state your goal I suspect that the reason for that close vote reason is because you give no example of what you tried or how you expect the feature to work. It's not a perfect close reason in this case, but if it truly is a new wonderous feature then I'd have expected to see a command line or something telling me how to use it.

Comment: Its first revision was legitimately really unclear; I'm guessing most of the closevotes were placed before it was edited into its final form.

Comment: @BenN - This means people still voted to close the question, which means even after the edit, problems remained.  Which also means, even after it was closed, it wasn't improved upon.